# jQuery script error in IE8

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer

In my application, when we mouse over on row the popup displayed. It's working fine in firefox browser, but in IE8 the following error displaying,

`'attr(..)' is null or not an object`

My actual code is,

```
var diamondinfo = "Test Content";
jQuery('#row').attr('title',diamondinfo);
```

Comment: Can you post the HTML code ?

Comment: What version of jQuery?

Comment: check if #row exists in your dom.

Comment: @Aboodred1 - if it works in Firefox I imagine that the element exists.